# jQuery toggle text and image not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, sprite

I am creating a dropdown accordion menu with jQuery.
I have worked on a few versions before and my script can work well before I add the image toggle.

But after I have added the image toggle script, the whole toggle is not functioning well.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showmore').click(
    function() {
      $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").toggle();
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up');
      if ($(this).text() == "Show") {
        $(this).text("Hide");
      } else {
        $(this).text("Show");
      }
      $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").toggleClass('selected');
    }
  )
})
```

```css
.title {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.sprite {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/bHTF8R/pinkarrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 9px;
  height: 6px;
  background-position: -9px 0;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 9px;
  height: 6px;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.arrow-down,
.arrow-up {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="title">
    <span class="showmore">Show<i class="sprite arrow-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <!--End of class Title-->

  <div class="dropdown">
    XXXXXXXXXX Content XXXXXXXXXX
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is that: Originally the content will be hidden, with a title "Show" with arrow down icon is shown. If I click on the title, the hidden content will be shown and the title will change to "Hide" and with arrow up icon.

Originally I can achieve the toggle with those text, however, after I have tried to add the image toggle script, it is not working.

```
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up');
```

Anyone can share with me your solution/opinion here? Thank you so much for your time of reading my question!

Comment: A fiddle is great, but please place all relevant code in the question. If jsFiddle goes down your question would have been unanswerable. As for the problem, it seems quite apparent if you run the snippet I edited in to the question and click 'show'...

Comment: Your browser console is telling you an error message.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you so much for your edit and concern. I don't really how to place the code here in a good way like you so I just used a jsFiddle. Thank you again for your reminder.

Comment: @David Actually I didn't get any error in console

Comment: closet is a typo. Type closest in there and it'll work.

Comment: Try using `$(this).cabinet` instead of `$(this).closet`

Comment: @Sammi: Then the code you're showing isn't the code you're using.  Provide code which *actually demonstrates the problem*.

Comment: @Maharkus  Sorry that I have made a mistake. I have corrected the typo; so for my case is that, the icon is shown at first, but after I clicked for the first time, the icon disappeared and the expand/collapse function can work, but just missing the icon toggle part. The code is the same as what I am using now and the same result as I had.

Comment: @David Sorry that I have made a mistake. I have corrected the typo; so for my case is that, the icon is shown at first, but after I clicked for the first time, the icon disappeared and the expand/collapse function can work, but just missing the icon toggle part. The code is the same as what I am using now and the same result as I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$(this).text("any text");
```

You *remove* the `<i>` element that you're using as an arrow.  The resulting markup becomes:

```
<span class="showmore">any text</span>
```

Since the `<i>` is now gone, there's nothing to toggle.  Instead of setting the text in the entire element, create a child element to hold the text:

```
<span class="showmore">
    <span>Show</span>
    <i class="sprite arrow-down"></i>
</span>
```

Then you can target that specific element to set the text:

```
$(this).find("span").text("any text");
```

---

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showmore').click(
    function() {
      $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").toggle();
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('arrow-down arrow-up');
      if ($(this).find("span").text() == "Show") {
        $(this).find("span").text("Hide");
      } else {
        $(this).find("span").text("Show");
      }
      $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").toggleClass('selected');
    }
  )
})
```

```css
.title {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.sprite {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/bHTF8R/pinkarrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 9px;
  height: 6px;
  background-position: -9px 0;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 9px;
  height: 6px;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.arrow-down,
.arrow-up {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="title">
    <span class="showmore">
      <span>Show</span>
      <i class="sprite arrow-down"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <!--End of class Title-->

  <div class="dropdown">
    XXXXXXXXXX Content XXXXXXXXXX
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: In my browser the styling on the "up arrow" doesn't look quite right.  Probably needs some tweaking.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed solution, David! I am having a bit misunderstanding about the .text() and really thanks for your explanation and reminder! My problem is solved now! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closet("div")
```

Should be:

```
$(this).closest("div")
```

Comment: While this fixes the syntax error, it doesn't address the OPs actual question.